# Making Tabs Swipeable in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

How to make the tabs in the JQ Mobile Navbar swipeable ? Is there  any inbuilt way of adding a attribute to the  div of nav-bar or Should we write any JQuery function?.
     [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7U3aX/)

```
 <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">

        <div data-role="navbar" >

            <ul>

                <li><a href="#clothing" data-ajax="false">Men</a>      
   </li>
                <li><a href="#footwear" data-ajax="false">Women</a>
  </li>
                <li><a href="#accessories" data-
   ajax="false">Kids</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/examples/swipe/swipe-page.html#&ui-state=dialog
    Example with source code available

Answer (score 0):

Nothing out of the box in the way you are asking for:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/navbar/

But you could add a jquery event (also as you allude to), something like:

```
$("div[data-role=navbar]").on("swiperight",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
     console.log("SWIPEY!!")
     return false;
});
```

(also see: http://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/)

...I have to wonder exactly what you are trying to do though?

Answer (score -1):

Try Below working Example, use it's code :

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Swipe tab</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="lessonhomepage">
      <!--content start-->
      <div data-role="content" id="tabscontent">
        <!--horizontal navigation tab start-->
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
          <div data-role="navbar" id="nav">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="ui-btn-active" href="#study" data-ajax="false">Study</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#quicktips" data-ajax="false">Quick Tips</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#quicktips3" data-ajax="false">Quick Tips</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#quicktips4" data-ajax="false">Quick Tips</a>
              </li>



            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="study">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </div>
          <div id="quicktips">
           There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
          </div>
          <div id="quicktips3">
           There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
          </div>
          <div id="quicktips4">
           There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
          </div>
          <div id="quicktips5">
           There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
          </div>
          <div id="quicktips6">
           There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
          </div>




          <!--horizontal navigation tab end-->
          <br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var panel = '<div data-theme="a" data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" id="leftpanel">sdf</div>';

     $(function() {
       $("body").prepend(panel);
       $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
     });

     var nextidx = 0;

     function changeNavTab(left) {
       var $tabs = $("div[data-role=navbar] li a", $("div[data-role=page].ui-page-active"));
       var curidx = $tabs.closest("a.ui-btn-active").parent().index();

       var tabcount = $tabs.length;

       if (left) {

           if (nextidx == tabcount - 1) {
               return(false);           
            } 
           else {
            nextidx = (curidx == $tabs.length - 1) ? 0 : curidx + 1;

            }

       } else {
          if (nextidx ==  0) {

               return(false);
            } 
           else {
               nextidx = (curidx == 0) ? $tabs.length - 1 : curidx - 1;

            } 

       }
       $tabs.eq(nextidx).click();
     }

     $("div[data-role=content]").on("swipeleft", function(event) {
       changeNavTab(true);
     });
     $("div[data-role=content]").on("swiperight", function(event) {
       changeNavTab(false);
     });


     // Navigation  Drawer Swipe Listener
     $("div[data-role=header]").on("swipeleft swiperight", function(e) {
       // save swipe direction right/left
       var dir = 'prev';
       if (e.type == 'swiperight') {
         dir = 'next';
       }
       if (dir == 'prev') {
         $('#leftpanel').panel('close');

       } else {
         $('#leftpanel').panel('open');

       }
     });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```